# How can one store images in an array (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to store images in an array using javascript. I also want to assign each image from that array to an option from a drop down list. The images are on different servers.

My function doesn’t work no matter what I try. Can someone please help me with this?

P.S – In this case I am only allowed to use javascript (homework :/) and I must use arrays to store the images.

HTML code:

```
<form action="#" method="get" accept charset="utf-8"> 

<select id="car">

<option> BMW </option>
<option> Mercedes </option>
<option> Audi </option>
<option> VW </option>

</select>

<input type="button" value="select" onclick="myFunction();">

</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {

var pictures = new Array();

pictures[0] = "https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect";
pictures[1] = "http://www.pruebas.pieldetoro.net/web/MERCEDES/DOSSIERES/w115/8-1.jpg";
pictures[2] = "https://pixabay.com/p-1203738/?no_redirect";
pictures[3] = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/13/13/45/vw-beetle-1042002_960_720.jpg";

var index = document.getElementById('car').selectedIndex;

document.images[0].src="https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect" + pictures[index] + ".jpg";
```

}

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why are you setting source with two links?

Comment: Ooops. My bad. Forgot to chage it. It should be the same as in the first element in the array.

Comment: Again, you're still setting source with two links. If index = 0, then your source link would be `https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirecthttps://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect.jpg". Is this intentional?

Comment: Well for a start `https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect` isn't an image. but https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/17/09/20/bmw-848904_1280.jpg is the image on that url and each time you change the image you will always have `https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect` in front of the new image path. Fro example `https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirecthttp://www.pruebas.pieldetoro.net/web/MERCEDES/DOSSIERES/w115/8-1.jpg`

Comment: First off, just to make sure you understand what's going on here... You're not storing images anywhere. You have Strings that contain a URI that tells the browser where to find an image. So really, your question is "How to store and access strings in a JavaScript array."

Instead of using the Array constructor, use the more common `var pictures = []` syntax. Instead of using the square-bracket notation and index, use Array.push.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `document.images[0].src=pictures[index];` ?

Comment: I am really new to this. To clarify: I just want to make a drop down list in html with some options and when a user chooses an option and clicks on "select" this javascript function should come in play retrieving the corresponding image. Since this is for homework I am only allowed to use arrays.

Comment: @JavaApprentice well so far you haven't done any of your assignment. You have asked questions here to get other people to do it for you. You will not learn from copy/paste. Be sure to read the source code and get a good understanding of it. This is why you couldn't see your own mistake on setting the new `src` You know in school they will also expect you to know how to use arrays since you managed to complete your homework and it isn't always as simple as copy/paste. Your teacher will know you haven't done it if you don't try learn from the answers/solutions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @NewToJS - Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work :

```
function myFunction()
{
    var pictures = [
        "https://pixabay.com/p-848904/?no_redirect",
        "http://www.pruebas.pieldetoro.net/web/MERCEDES/DOSSIERES/w115/8-1.jpg",
        "https://pixabay.com/p-1203738/?no_redirect",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/13/13/45/vw-beetle-1042002_960_720.jpg"
    ];
    var index = document.getElementById('car').selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById('img1').src = pictures[index];
```

Comment: Just tried it, but it still doesn't work :/

Why do you have 'img1'? Where does that come from?

Comment: You just have to add this line after your form : <img id="img1">